# What is the VB.NET equivalent of this C# code (convert an ASCII string to hexadecimal)? 

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

What is the VB.NET equivalent of this C# code (convert an ASCII string to hexadecimal)?

```
public static string AsciiToHex(string asciiString)
{
    string hex = "";

    StringBuilder sBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < asciiString.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuffer.Append(Convert.ToInt32(asciiString[i]).ToString("x"));
    }
    hex = sBuffer.ToString().ToUpper();

    return hex;
}
```

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ Allows you to convert C# to VB.net.

Comment: You *do* realize that that the number of digits is variable, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

1. Why use a `for` loop where a `foreach` look also works? (The answer is: not)
2. The `ToUpper` is redundant when we choose the correct formatting flag (`X`).
3. The variable `hex` is useless.
4. `Convert.ToInt32` can be shortened to `(int)`.
5. The name “ASCII” is actually wrong – you are working with Unicode here.
6. Usually, this calls for a padding since the `ToString("x")` result has variable length: for character codes < 16 it yields a single character!

This leaves us with:

```
public static string CharToHex(string str) {
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in str)
        buffer.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", (int) c);
    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

… and translated into VB:

```
Public Shared Function CharToHex(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim buffer As New StringBuilder()

    For Each c As Char in str
        buffer.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", Asc(c))
    End For

    Return buffer.ToString()
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Public Shared Function AsciiToHex(asciiString As String) As String
 Dim hex As String = ""
 Dim sBuffer As New StringBuilder()
 For i As Integer = 0 To asciiString.Length - 1
  sBuffer.Append(Convert.ToInt32(asciiString(i)).ToString("x"))
 Next
 hex = sBuffer.ToString().ToUpper()
 Return hex
End Function
```

via http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Which is one of many tools that can do C# to VB conversions, and can by found using this search: http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+to+vb+converter&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC

Comment: Instead of `Convert.ToInt32` I would use `AscW` …

Comment: Darn you, the captcha slowed me down.

Comment: @Konrad: Is there a particular reason that you'd use a VB-specific "pseudofunction" (for lack of a better term) rather than a CLS-compliant function that will be clearer to anyone else reading the code? I'm not saying that it's a bad idea *per se*, just that I try to get people to use library functions if there's no particular advantage to the language-specific construct.

Comment: @Adam: usually I always favour the framework functions but I hate the `Convert` class with a fiery passion. These “everything goes” functions that perform just about any conversion even if they are not meaningful is just dangerous. Therefore I look on such calls in code as a warning sign (and I wouldn’t use it in the C# code, either) because it’s simply not obvious which conversion is going on. Furthermore, the existence of this static helper class is pure code smell. Using it is no better than using un-OOP “free” functions.

Comment: @Konrad: I can't argue with the idea that it's unclear what's happening. Admittedly, at first glance I assumed that `Convert.Int32(char)` was similar to `Convert.Int32(string)`, in that it's basically an analog for `int.Parse`. It would probably be more advisable for the original C# code to cast the `char` to an `int` and use `AscW` in VB.NET

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Shared Function AsciiToHex(asciiString As String) As String
 Dim hex As String = ""

 Dim sBuffer As New StringBuilder()
 For i As Integer = 0 To asciiString.Length - 1
  sBuffer.Append(Convert.ToInt32(asciiString(i)).ToString("x"))
 Next
 hex = sBuffer.ToString().ToUpper()

 Return hex
End Function
```

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/